# Delete records from SQL table in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010, delete-row

I am trying to delete records from my table but unable to do so. I have window form with Insert, Update, Delete and Save button. I can insert data but I can't delete specific or any records from that table. Below is my code.

Whenever I click 'delete' button I get ("Error while deleting record on table..." & ex.Message, "Delete Records") msgbox only.

Am I missing something? Please advise. Any help would be great. Thank you!

```
Private Sub Deletebtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Deletebtn.Click

    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Try
        con.ConnectionString = "Server=USRAG-L-0067215\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Alamo Products_Design Data;Trusted_Connection=True"
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "Delete From Design_Parameters where DesignID= ? "
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to Delete this Record?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) = DialogResult.No Then

            MsgBox("Operation Cancelled")

            Exit Sub

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error while deleting record on table..." & ex.Message, "Delete Records")

    Finally

        con.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: `DesignID= ?` will not work, did you mean `DesignID='?'`

Comment: You're using a parameterized query, but have not assigned a value to the parameter. If that's not the problem, you'll need to post the actual exception you're receiving.

Comment: Also, there is no point in asking about record deletion if you already did it. Your code will show `Operation cancelled` when it really wasn't.

Comment: @alroc: parameters in SQL are denoted with `@`, not `?`.

Comment: @Neolisk..Thx for your reply. Even If I put '?', It gives me return value of designID with '?' correct? What do you suggest?

Comment: @alroc..Thx for your reply. I updated my question with actual exception I am getting. :)

Comment: In SQL, variables are denoted with `@`. In ADO.NET parameterized queries, `?` can be the placeholder for the parameter (I think - maybe it's changed?).

Comment: Please don't tell us which line you get with the exception, post **the actual exception**.

Comment: @alroc: not sure about ADO.NET, OP is clearly using `Sql` classes, so it must be `@` in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add parameter for DesignID

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Try
        con.ConnectionString = "Server=USRAG-L-0067215\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Alamo Products_Design Data;Trusted_Connection=True"
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "Delete From Design_Parameters where DesignID= @DesignID"
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@DesignID", yourvaluehere))
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to Delete this Record?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) = DialogResult.No Then

            MsgBox("Operation Cancelled")

            Exit Sub

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error while deleting record on table..." & ex.Message, "Delete Records")

    Finally

        con.Close()
    End Try
```

Comment: Thx for your help and code, One question....What value should I put in "yourvaluehere"? cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@DesignID", yourvaluehere))

Comment: IT should be the value of the primary key "DesignID" of the record you want to delete. Please put the statement "cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()" in the "else" part of the condition (MessageBox.Show): otherwise, you will delete the record, ask the question, but be unable to roll back. Serge